# SIgnalR - How can I use an Hub stored in a folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm developing an ASP Web Form project in C#.

I have 2 SignalR Hubs:

1. 'Hub1' that is in the root of the project (\Hub1.cs)
2. 'Hub2' that is in a folder (\Games\Hub2.cs)

My program.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapSignalR();            
    }
}
```

When I load a page, only the Hub1 is loaded because I use

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

On js script I use

```
$.connection.Hub2.client.Foo=... ;//some funtion
    and
$.connection.hub.start();//starts the hub
```

I can't see the Hub2 also if I write `<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>`

How can I use it? I need to put Hubs in a different folders.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you provide full urls then it will work. For example (js client):

```
    // yoursite/subfolder/signalr
    var connection = $.hubConnection("https://yoursite.com/games/signalr", { useDefaultPath: false });        
var proxy = connection.createHubProxy('hub2');
    // your custom funcs..
    proxy.on('sayHello', function() {
                                alert("hello");
                            });
    //another important part ONLY if you have another server app installed in 'games'
        $.connection.hub.url = "https://yousite.com/games";
        connection.start()
        .done(function(){ console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + connection.id); })
        .fail(function(){ console.log('Could not connect'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

All hubs are in /signalr/hubs without reference to folders. But all of that must starts with letter in lower case.

Can you try this?

```
$.connection.hub2.client.Foo=... ;//some funtion
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It give me '$.connection.hub2 is undefined'

Comment: Can you write in browser console "$.connection" and in output object find hubs? What hubs you see?

Comment: I solved: I had 2 Hub2 in the project (one was hidden) and signalR couldn't load it. Anyway Thanks!